# Inserting a case specific checklist into the form

Tags: filemaker

I am working on a database to track equipment maintenance for the department. I am using FileMaker.
I am trying to insert a checklist of maintenance work that needs to be done for each specific item.
For example, if maintenance is done on the Equipment A, it will insert a Checklist A.
Thank you,
Val

Comment: You'll want to write more about your solution. Are you looking for a simple set of checkboxes in a field with each item in a Checklist? Are you looking to populate a Tasks table for records of Checklist A? Are you looking to do something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You want a related table of checklist items that has a relationship to your equipment, i.e. id_equipment in a Maintenance_Items table.  You can put more than one equipment id in each maint. items record to relate it to more than one item.  Then create a value list based on that relationship so that you only see the maint. items related to that piece of equipment.

This can be very simple or there can be a lot more to it depending on your system.  We do really need to see more of your system or get more details to give you a better answer.